# Auto run tests before app build in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, build.gradle

I've written two test cases `LoginTest` and `SignUpTest` using [JUnit](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwibz7i__93IAhVKFZAKHa10Anc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjunit.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFDm94Yeqcvj7vFx6CaiUWEGo3hkQ&sig2=aX60XcrLLJ7qwLIyks3Cow) and a Test Suite `SessionUnitTestSuite`. Every time I want to build and run my app, I have to run the test suite (by selecting the Test Suite and then clicking in "Run")  before and, if the test passes, run my app (by selecting the app module and then clicking in "Run").

Is there a way to automatically run the tests before running my app module and cancel the installation of my app if the tests fail?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to `Run/Debug Configurations`, and select your application configuration. At the bottom of the right panel, under `Before launch:`, click the `+` button, and select `Run another configuration`. There, choose the configuration for running your tests.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add this configuration to the *build.gradle* file ?

Comment: cannot find the **Run 'Unit tests'** option in new Android studio

Comment: @Ezio It's under "Run another configuration"

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to have them run every time I *save a file*?

Comment: @regmoraes Yes it is.. Check the **share** button that lie on the right side of configuration name and then add the file under `project_directory/.idea/runConfigurations/` to VCS.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig#nameshare

Comment: @Ezio at first you have to press 'play' button on test file and select creating configuration from the dropdown menu